# Android: how to check the flash light is available on device?

Tags: android

How I check the flash light available on device?also want to know how can I On/Off the flash light?
  I have put the code but not working right now?
  I search out this 
        [http://gitorious.org/rowboat/frameworks-base/commit/eb9cbb8fdddf4c887004b20b504083035d57a15f](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/com/android/server/LightsService.java#LightsService)
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/com/android/server/LightsService.java#LightsService

Please can tell which I should use?
Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to check if device has flash light led android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413938/how-to-check-if-device-has-flash-light-led-android)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the following

```
context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

which will return true if a flash is available, false if not.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html for more information.

Comment: I have my hands on cheap chinese android tablet, where this returns true, even though there is no flash support. I also found that getSupportedFlashModes() returns null in this case, so could probably be used to double check if flash is available.

Comment: 2013 Nexus 7 also returns true. There is no flash.

Comment: Nexus 7 returns true, and then getSupportedFlashModes() returns a list with one entry. A string that reads, "off". :-(

Comment: I mention how to fix for the Nexus 7 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413938/how-to-check-if-device-has-flash-light-led-android/19599365#19599365

Comment: Iiconbit nt-3702s also returning true.

Answer (score 5):

```
boolean hasFlash =this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

or

```
public boolean hasFlash() {
        if (camera == null) {
            return false;
        }

        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

        if (parameters.getFlashMode() == null) {
            return false;
        }

        List<String> supportedFlashModes = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();
        if (supportedFlashModes == null || supportedFlashModes.isEmpty() || supportedFlashModes.size() == 1 && supportedFlashModes.get(0).equals(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

First you get supported flash modes:

```
camera = Camera.open(i);    // Introduced in API level 9
parameters = camera.getParameters();
String[] flashModes = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();
```

And then you check if this array contains the correct constants like: "auto", "on", "off".

More info in:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FLASH_MODE_AUTO

Answer (score 0):

This can help full to turn on/off flash light of device. This is give me satisfaction, Hope be useful to you also.

**Turn On camera Flash**

```
camera = Camera.open();
Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
camera.setParameters(p);
camera.startPreview();
```

**Turn Off camera Flash**

```
camera = Camera.open();
Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
camera.setParameters(p);
camera.stopPreview();
```

**Put this Permission in manifest file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

For more detail you can go [HERE.](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-turn-onoff-camera-ledflashlight-in-android/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.