# How to check, on Android, if device has flash light led

Tags: android, android-camera

How can I check if a device has a camera led (flashlight)? I am talking about devices with android OS?

I have seen solutions some solutions which talks about how to turn the led on and off but what will happen if the device doesn't even has a led.

for turning on the camera I am using `camera.open()`

Comment: Did u got the solution for your question bcoz i am also looking for solution of same question..

Comment: the answer I have checked as answered

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The other answers

```
boolean hasFlash = this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

Does not work for the new 2013 Nexus 7. The following code will work:

```
public boolean hasFlash() {
        if (camera == null) {
            return false;
        }

        Camera.Parameters parameters;
        try {
            parameters = camera.getParameters();
        } catch (RuntimeException ignored)  {
            return false;
        }

        if (parameters.getFlashMode() == null) {
            return false;
        }

        List<String> supportedFlashModes = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();
        if (supportedFlashModes == null || supportedFlashModes.isEmpty() || supportedFlashModes.size() == 1 && supportedFlashModes.get(0).equals(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH) does not work on Wildfire S. Your method works fine for me, tested on Nexus 4, Nexus 5, Xperia Z1, Note 3, Wildfire S and Galaxy S (i9000, no flash).

Comment: First solution working on Samsung S5, the second not.

Comment: @PrimožKralj Thanks for the info, which of the above checks failed on the S5? Do you have another solution that will work for both?

Comment: I am not able to test on any other device right now, but will try in the following days and report back. What I did is I combined both methods in this answer: first checking with the first method and if it returns false (no flash), proceed with the second method.

Comment: Both solution is not working in Lenovo tablet TB-X304L

Answer (score 6):

`getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)` returns true if the device has flash. See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#hw-features) for more details

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to check whether the flash is available by checking system features:

```
boolean hasFlash = this.getPackageManager()
                       .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

(provided you are in an `Activity`).  If not, than use some sort of `context` in place of `this`.

P.S. Note that this information is quite easy to find if you actually try searching for it.

Answer (score 2):

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            Log.e("err", "Device has no camera!");
            return;
        }       
        camera = Camera.open();
        p = camera.getParameters();
        flashModes = p.getSupportedFlashModes();
if(flashModes==null){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LED Not Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else
                {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LED  Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I check if LED flash is available. Also you don't need to have the Camera permission to run this method.

```
private fun isLedFlashAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
    // method 1
    if (context.packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
        return true
    }

    // method 2
    val cameraManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
    for (id in cameraManager.cameraIdList) {
        if (cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(id).get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE) == true) {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```